# How do I set a join table's extra attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

These are my models

```
class Product
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :orders, :through => :line_items
end

class LineItem 
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

  validates :quantity, presence: true
end

class Order
    has_many :line_items
    has_many :products, :through => :line_items
end
```

I can do `@order.products << @product` to associate a product with an order, but I can't figure out how to also set the quantity in the join table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the line item directly and specify its quantity and product.

Try something like this

```
@product = Product.find(1)
@order.line_items.create(product_id: @product.id, quantity: 100)
```

Comment: I had to do `line_items.build` instead of `line_items.create` to get it to work, but otherwise this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could build up `@line_item` instead of the `@product` and then append that to `@order`'s line items.

```
@line_item.quantity = 100
@line_item.product = Product.find(10)
@order.line_items << @line_item
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it by hand or through a form ?

If by hand you would just have to find the product in the LineItem's relation and update it:

```
x = @order.line_items.last
x.quantity = 2
```

edit: 
Baconator507's answer is the fastest

Answer (score 0):

No need to join table's extra attribute, it's already there.

```
Order#line_items # will return all information's you need
```

But if you want return products in specific order with quantity try out following code.

First, add `quantity` as `attr_accessor :quantity` to `Product.rb`

Than, remove the following line `has_many :products, :through => :line_items` in `Order.rb` create `products` method instead

```
def products
  products_list = []
  line_items.each do |item|
    item.product.quantity = item.quantity
    products_list << item.product
  end
  products_list
end

order = Order.last
order.products # will return list of products with quantity attribute
```